# No error specified but it doesn't do what I expect or want

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason the code below brings up no errors but brings up the same 'puzzle' each time(NOTE the puzzles will be added later once code is working) can anyone suggest possible causes and solutions

```
import random
correct = 0
not_again = []
puzzle = ["SUP","SAS","FUN","IS"]
answer = ["SUP","SAS","FUN","IS"]
life = 10
print("Welcome to the labrynth")
print("You are an explorer")
print("You have entered the maze in the hope of finding the lost treasure")
print("There will be a door blocking your entrance and preceedings at which a puzzle will be presented")
print("If you get the answer correct the door will open")
print("Then another 9 puzzles arrive at which point there will be the ultimate puzzle giving you the treasure")
print("If you get it wrong you lose one of ten lives")
def puzzles():
    global correct
    global not_again
    global puzzle
    global answer
    global life


    print("A stone door blocks your path")
    print("An inscription is on it: a riddle")
    select = random.randint(1,4)
    select -= 1
    select = int(select)
    if select in not_again:
        select = random.randint(1,4)
        select -= 1
    for select in range(len(puzzle)):
        puz = puzzle[select]
    print(puz)
    doesit = input("Type your answer")
    if doesit == answer[select]:
        print("The door opens!")
        correct += 1
        not_again.append(select)
        print(not_again)
        if correct < 10:
            puzzles()
    elif doesit != answer[select]:
        life -= 1
        not_again.append(select)
        if correct < 10:
            puzzles()
puzzles()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if this is your issue, but you seem to be unintentionally overwriting `select` variable in the first for loop.

The way I understand `random.randint(1,4)` should generate an integer in the specified range that determines what puzzle will be served to the user. That number is stored in the variable `select`. However in the loop

```
for select in range(len(puzzle)):
    puz = puzzle[select]
```

you're overwriting that variable with the length of the list `puzzle`, which is static and always "3". Try eliminating that for-loop and see if that produces your desired outcome.

```
def puzzles():
global correct
global not_again
global puzzle
global answer
global life


print("A stone door blocks your path")
print("An inscription is on it: a riddle")
select = random.randint(1,4)
select -= 1
select = int(select)
if select in not_again:
    select = random.randint(1,4)
    select -= 1
puz = puzzle[select]
print(puz)
doesit = input("Type your answer")
if doesit == answer[select]:
    print("The door opens!")
    correct += 1
    not_again.append(select)
    print(not_again)
    if correct < 10:
        puzzles()
elif doesit != answer[select]:
    life -= 1
    not_again.append(select)
    if correct < 10:
        puzzles()
```

*(To the community - this is my first answer, if I violated something let me know and I will rectify)*

Comment: Thank you it seems to be in order